# Automatically add row in ng-grid when tabbing last cell

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ng-grid

I need one working example, to add row while tabbing last cell

I have four cells in one row once we filled and tabbing from last cell it should be add new row.

I tried but i'm unable to find.
http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-grid/  (Edit On Focus Cell Selection Example)

```
[http://codepen.io/calendee/pen/buCHf][1]
```

in inside row i have text inupt.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add your logic inside this handler:

```
$scope.gridApi.edit.on.afterCellEdit($scope,function(rowEntity, colDef){


})
```